# Making a zebra pattern in ASPX Repeater

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater in my webpage, and I would like to change the background colors. First one will be blue, second yellow, then blue and so on.. I have the below table but do not know how to implement a javascript or css on the repeater. Can anyone assist?

```
            <asp:Repeater ID="cevapgoruntuleyici" runat="server"
                OnItemDataBound="cevapgoruntuleyici_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table width="693" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#CCCCCC">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" class="style2">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblcevapno" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblcevapdetay" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="344">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblcevaplayan" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td width="343" class="style3">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblcevaptarih" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="CevapEk" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="CevapEkIndir" Visible="false" runat="server" OnClick="CevapEkIndir_Click" />

                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Alternating background colors are done with CSS. Search for `nth-child(even)` and `nth-child(odd)` for how to do it. Don't do this in your ASP.NET code.

Comment: Thanks, css seems to be much easier in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this.  I'll go over 2 of them.

Since you are using a Repeater control, you can define an `<ItemTemplate>`, which you've done.  You can also define an`< AlternatingItemTemplate>`, which refers to the "odd" rows.  Doing this, you can specify a background color or class.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="cevapgoruntuleyici" runat="server"
    OnItemDataBound="cevapgoruntuleyici_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table width="693" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#CCCCCC" **class="odd-row"**>
            ....
        </table>
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <table width="693" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#CCCCCC" **class="even-row"**>
            ....
        </table>
        <br />
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

You could also use CSS to accomplish this, which would be much more simple if the row contents are exactly the same (you just want a different background color).  Encapsulate the repeated tables in a main table and add a class to each table row of the new larger table.

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Alternating Item Template then using the css code worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Your current structure will create multiple tables i.e for each item in your collection a separate table will be rendered which is wrong. You need just one table with multiple rows so to fix this have the table definition in *HeaderTemplate* and *FooterTemplate* resp. as shown below:-

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table width="693" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
           bordercolor="#CCCCCC">
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="style2">
              <asp:Label ID="lblcevapno" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
              <br />
              <asp:Label ID="lblcevapdetay" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
    </tr>
     ....
<FooterTemplate>
     </table>
</FooterTemplate>
```

This will render just one table with as many rows as many present in your collection. Next simply find the *odd* and *even* rows in the table and set the CSS color like this:-

```
 <style>
    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: red;
    }

    tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
```